# Combine two queries from different tables and sort by a common column?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this two queries

```
SELECT  consejos.consejo as value,
                            consejos.id,
                            consejos.texto,
                            consejos.votos               
                    FROM consejos
                    ORDER BY fecha DESC
```

And

```
SELECT  preguntas.pregunta as value,
                            preguntas.id,
                            preguntas.texto,
                            preguntas.votos               
                    FROM preguntas
                    ORDER BY fecha DESC
```

Is there any simple way to get both results in the same query and sort by `fecha` column? and would it be possible to add a field to determinate which table is a row from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `union`:

```
SELECT value, id, texto, votos, source_table from (
  SELECT  consejos.consejo as value,
                              consejos.id,
                              consejos.texto,
                              consejos.votos,
                              'consejos' as source_table,
                              fecha               
                      FROM consejos
UNION
  SELECT  preguntas.pregunta as value,
                              preguntas.id,
                              preguntas.texto,
                              preguntas.votos,
                              'preguntas' as source_table,
                              fecha                              
                      FROM preguntas
) as A ORDER BY fecha DESC
```

**EDIT:**
for your additional request, to add a column indicating from which table it came- you can just add to the columns list in the select `'consejos' as source_table` to the first, and `'preguntas' as source_table` to the second

**Second EDIT (for strawberry, is this a test or something? did I pass :)?)**
add `fecha` to the inner queries, but not to the wrapping one if you dont want it there

Comment: I had to select `fecha as ff` in both querys and sort by `ff` because didn't find `fecha`, but it works ! :)

Answer (score 1):

Use `UNION ALL`

```
Select * From (
SELECT  consejos.consejo as value,
                            consejos.id,
                            consejos.texto,
                            consejos.votos               
                    FROM consejos

UNION ALL

SELECT  preguntas.pregunta as value,
                            preguntas.id,
                            preguntas.texto,
                            preguntas.votos               
                    FROM preguntas ) t
   ORDER BY t.fecha DESC
```

Comment: Nearly - but not quite

Comment: @Strawberry you find 'something' in everyone's answers, but where is yours? :P

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT consejos.consejo AS value
    ,consejos.id
    ,consejos.texto
    ,consejos.votos
FROM consejos
UNION ALL
SELECT preguntas.pregunta AS value
    ,preguntas.id
    ,preguntas.texto
    ,preguntas.votos
FROM preguntas
ORDER BY fecha DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select id,texto,votos from ((SELECT consejos.consejo as value,
                            consejos.id as id,
                            consejos.texto as texto ,
                            consejos.votos  as votos             
                    FROM consejos) UNION (SELECT  preguntas.pregunta as value,
                            preguntas.id as id,
                            preguntas.texto as texto,
                            preguntas.votos  as votos             
                    FROM preguntas )) as tb ORDER BY fecha DESC
```